# shell script to run multiple scripts from different shells

Tags: shell

I want to run 2 different scripts from a single master shell script.

- The first one uses the following command "rosh -n  -l abcd" (It will log me in to the server with the user abcd and on the same shell I need to run the other `script#2` and `script#3` ...etc.)

  Script#2- From there I need to change user using `su - xyz` and provide a password (it is fine if I can hardcode this in the file) (Script name is logintoServer)

  Script#3- Run some script in the same shell to verify start of stop of server...

I have done the following but failed

- I have one script which has `rosh -n <servername> -l abcd /bin/sh -c "su - xyz"` (I have to run this command in the same shell)

  The below are the errors:

  1. I am getting error while executing "standard in must be a tty"
  2. I have tried to create 2 different scripts and run, but the problem is once the first script is run it does not run the 2nd script till I exit the script. (I need to run the 2nd script from the sub-shell created by the 1st script....)

Comment: That's a fiendishly complex setup.  I'd probably not both to try, but there are times when I'm lazy.  If you need the user `xyz` to run scripts `script2` and `script3` after the `su` takes effect, then you probably need to specify `su - xyz -c "script2; script3"` or something similar.  You may still be hosed by the `standard input must be a tty` error; fixing that may require `expect` or something similar.  My mind is frazzled just trying to think through what you're doing.

Comment: what's the output of `rosh -n <servername> -l abcd tty`? what's the output of `tty` when running `rosh -n <servername> -l abcd` interactively?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, for your quick response.How ever if I run the Script#1 (rosh -n <servername> -l abcd) in shell script and then execute Script#2 then it works and ask for password as input. But it fails if I want to do in a single script. like (./firstScript && ./secondScript) it does not prompt for the password and gives the tty error.

Comment: The output of the (rosh -n <servername> -l abcd) is just a shell line($) with the  user abcd logged in. Then from there I need to change the user using su

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `rosh` and I don't have a man page for `rosh` but a similar problem exists with `ssh`:

```
ssh localhost /bin/bash -c 'echo x' # (prints nothing)
ssh localhost "/bin/bash -c 'echo x'" # x
ssh localhost "/bin/bash -c 'tty'" # not a tty
ssh -t localhost "/bin/bash -c 'tty'" # /dev/pts/12\nConnection to localhost closed.
ssh localhost "/bin/bash -c 'su - $USER'" # su: must be run from a terminal
ssh -t localhost "/bin/bash -c 'su - $USER'"
```

the last asked for a password and then gave me a shell, so that would be 2 of 3 steps.

so one idea is to see if `rosh` has the -t option, too and the other is to enclose `/bin/bash...` with quotes, too (will require some escaping for the 3rd level).

What does `rosh` say with equivalent commands?

**UPDATE**
latest state:

```
rosh -n $host -l abcd -t "/bin/sh -c 'su - $user'"
```

Next I would save one step by saying `/bin/su - xyz` instead `/bin/sh -c 'su - xyz'`, then you can use single quotes later, e.g.

```
rosh -n $host -l abcd -t "/bin/su - $user -c 'echo $PATH'"
```

this should print $PATH as seen by the echo command. Apparently it doesn't contain java. try `man su`, `which java`, `man which`. 
`su ... -c cmd` runs cmd with the shell specified in /etc/passwd, so say `</etc/passwd grep $user` on the remote machine to find out which shell is used. if it's bash you can change $PATH in .bashrc or so, for other shells I don't know exactly.

Or specify an absolute path when launching java.

regarding password: with ssh I managed to use private key / public key and `ssh-agent`. For `rosh` I don't know if that works, too.

Comment: Hi I am getting the following while using rosh for all the above commands " rosh: Device must be specified with -n or -i or via path"

Comment: I got it worked by using the following one "rosh -n <servername> -l abcd -t "/bin/sh -c 'su - xyz'". However it ask me the password to be inputted from command line now. Now one problem is it complains about being java not present,but it is there in the sub-shell where I am running my script#2 or Script#3. Any suggestion, Thanks for all of your response it was helpful so far.

Comment: good news. `rosh: Device must be specified` is because `ssh <host>` corresponds to `rosh -n <host>`. regarding the rest I'll update my answer. btw you can use backticks '`' instead double quotes '"' in your comments to render things in monospace font.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, It was help ful

Comment: in that case you should upvote or accept the answer so that the next user having the same problem sees that it's solved.